# WPF Binding UI (source) with Property (destination)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I have a `public string` property which I would like to change when I lose focus on a `TextBox`.
The property:

```
public string Name { get; set; }
```

The `TextBox`:

```
<DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
    <Label DockPanel.Dock="Left" Content="Name:" />
    <TextBox />
</DockPanel>
```

May anyone please help me with that?

Comment: do you want to update the data of the TextBox when focus has changed, or do you want the binding from the TextBox to your Name property to occur once the TextBox has LostFocus?

Comment: @d.moncada As soon as the `TextBox` has `LostFocus` I want the property to update to the content that is inside the `TextBox`

Comment: Okay.. in that case, see Martin's answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a simple binding:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"></TextBox>
```

Because `LostFocus` is the default setting for the binding updates of the source, you can skip this attribute and it gets down to this expression:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Name}"></TextBox>
```

or event without the path as Will suggests :-)

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBox>
```

Comment: It's even simpler when you don't use the redundant "Path="